# Нужна помощь с деревом

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

строю в своем веб-приложении дерево, с помощью плагина jsTree, использую функцию `open_all`, проблема в том что если дерево очень большое, оно очень медленно открывается, так как все ноды открываются параллельно, собственно вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы функция `open_all` открывала не сразу все ноды, а допустим по 5-10 штук, открыла первые 10, потом следующие?

Пример: `title="Відкрити дерево" onclick="$('#jstreeBody').jstree('open_all');"`